# How to move selected track to top of playlist

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, foobar2000

In foobar2000's playlist editor, is there any simple way to move the currently selected track(s) either to the top of the list or to after the currently playing track? I used to have a shortcut key to do this in winamp (can't remember if that required a plugin or not), and am missing the ability to do it in foobar2000.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a component for this but I'm not sure. You can right-click (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click depending on your context menu setup) one or more files and select *Add to playback queue*. This won't change the track order but it will change the playback order. After the current track ends it will jump to the tracks you've added to the queue (the *Playing* column will show numbers in brackets for these). If you want you can also assign a direct keyboard shortcut to *Add to playback queue* via `Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Answer (score -1):

Windows copy/cut/paste hotkeys work with items in the playlists, so you can quickly cut an entry from the bottom; Home key; paste at the top.